# How can i convert html entities in my twitter bot?

Tags: javascript, python, html, twitter, tweepy

i'm a begginer programmer and i'm having troubles with my twitter bot. The idea of the bot is tweet an daily verse of bible everyday, and that's what I got so far:

```
import tweepy
import requests

api = tweepy.Client(
    consumer_key='',
    consumer_secret='',
    access_token='-',
    access_token_secret='',
)
response = requests.get("https://www.biblegateway.com/votd/get/?format=json&version=NVI-PT")
verse_of_the_day = response.json()["votd"]["text"]

try:
    tweet=api.create_tweet(text=("Aqui está o versículo do dia: \n") + verse_of_the_day)
    print(tweet)
except:
    print("something is wrong")
```

the problem is that some characters appear as HTML entity and not as the "character itself" and
what I hope is to fix these characters that are in html entity

Comment: did you try using
```import html
 html.unescape(verse_of_the_date)
```

Comment: didn't work here

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work, could you elaborate? I just tried it locally and it printed it as expected

Comment: I tried it here in vscode and it had no effect

Comment: Can you add the code you used for the second attempt? And the output you got

Comment: I just put it below "verse_of_the_day = response.json()["votd"]["text"]" . I didn't understand where should I put

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unescape the HTML entities using the `html.unescape()` function

```py
import tweepy
import requests
import html

api = tweepy.Client(
    consumer_key='',
    consumer_secret='',
    access_token='-',
    access_token_secret='',
)
response = requests.get("https://www.biblegateway.com/votd/get/?format=json&version=NVI-PT")
verse_of_the_day = html.unescape(response.json()["votd"]["text"]) #unescapes the string

try:
    tweet=api.create_tweet(text=("Aqui está o versículo do dia: \n") + verse_of_the_day)
    print(tweet)
except:
    print("something is wrong")
```